# How do you parameterize an ADF copy pipeline to backdate and backfill using tumbling window trigger

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

So I am new to ADF. I have created a copy pipeline that uses the timestamp in the filename to create a date partition in my sink ADLSgen2.

Unfortunately I cannot attach images.

The sequence is like this:

1. GetMetadata activity (extracted childItems)
2. Foreach activity (setting[@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems])
3. Inside the foreach I used a SetVariable activity
   `(VARIABLES-@concat(substring(split(item().name,'_')[2],0,4),'/',substring(split(item().name,'_')[2],4,2),'/', substring(split(item().name,'_')[2],6,2)))`
   to split the filename and extract the date which I then linked my copy activity with this directory

   ````
   ```'Year=', formatDateTime(variables('datetime'), 'yyyy'), '/',
   ```'Month=', formatDateTime(variables('datetime'), 'MM'), '/',
   ```'Day=', formatDateTime(variables('datetime'), 'dd')
   ```))**
   ````

The files are in the format H_ODP_20201125_092436_00.CSV

The pipeline working fine but the problem is i want to run only files for a specific date and need assistance parameterizing it.

I want to be able to backdate and backfill for any specific date using the tumbling window trigger Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to extract the date and copy all files under this date?

Comment: I want to be able to extract the date and run a tumbling window to copy the data, so yes that is correct.